# Vectorization guidelnes for jax

Tags: python, jax

suppose I have a function (for simplicity, covariance between two  series, though the question is more general):

```
def cov(x, y):
   return jnp.dot((x-jnp.mean(x)), (y-jnp.mean(y)))
```

Now I have a "dataframe" `D` (a 2-dimenisonal array, whose columns are my series) and I want to vectorize `cov` in such a way that the application of the vectorized function produces the covariance matrix. Now, there is an obvious way of doing it:

```
cov1 = jax.vmap(cov, in_axes=(None, 1))
cov2 = jax.vmap(cov1, in_axes=(1, None))
```

but that seems a little clunky. Is there a "canonical" way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to express logic equivalent to nested `for` loops with `vmap`, then yes it requires nested vmaps. I think what you've written is probably as canonical as you can get for an operation like this, although it might be slightly more clear if written using decorators:

```python
from functools import partial

@partial(jax.vmap, in_axes=(1, None))
@partial(jax.vmap, in_axes=(None, 1))
def cov(x, y):
   return jnp.dot((x-jnp.mean(x)), (y-jnp.mean(y)))
```

For this particular function, though, note that you can express the same thing using a single dot product if you wish:

```python
result = jnp.dot((x - x.mean(0)).T, (y - y.mean(0)))
```

Comment: Thanks! The particular function is actually built in, so that was not a great example (I was actually writing a robust covariance, where the innermost function is different).